# Disable options when other options are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to build is a dynamic selection process. To elaborate, the end-user is only allowed to select a total of 4 lines (across both unlimited and basic).

So, if they select 2 **unlimited phone** lines, then boxes 3 and 4 under **basic phone** should be given the class `.mb-disabled` which prevents selection of those two options (since they can only have 4 total).

If in another scenario they were to choose 1 **unlimited phone** line and 3 **basic phone** lines, then boxes 2, 3, and 4 under **unlimited** would be disabled, and box 4 under **basic** would be disabled.

Here is a diagram to illustrate what I mean further:

[phone selection diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FJmk.png)

I tried earlier using `.each()` to assign a `data-unl-number='x'` to the unlimited miniboxes, and a `data-basic-number='x'` to the basic miniboxes, but I was unable to produce anything that a) functioned properly and b) was relatively clean code. It quickly became a mess of if/else statements and I am hoping to avoid that.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

-M

```js
var $unlminibox = $('.unl-selection-container > .minibox');
var $basicminibox = $('.basic-selection-container > .minibox');

$(function() {
  $unlminibox.on('click', toggleBox);
  $basicminibox.on('click', toggleBox);
})

function toggleBox(e) {
  if($(this).hasClass('mb-disabled')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass('mb-selected').siblings().removeClass('mb-selected');
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('mb-selected')) {
    racePhone = true;
  } else {
    racePhone = false;
  }
}
```

```css
h2 {
 color:#787878;
 font-weight:700;
}

.divider {
 background-color:#e8e8e8;
 height:2px;
}

.prime-aux {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 padding:15px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}

.aux-phn-subtext {
 color:#787878;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:600;
 font-style:italic;
}

.itembox-container {
 display:flex;
}

.boxes-2 {
 width:calc((100% - 25px)/2);
 margin:10px;
 padding: 10px;
}

.itembox {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:10px;
}

.user-selected {
 border:5px solid #E16E5B;
}

.itembox > h4 {
 color:#22ddc0;
 font-weight:700;
}

span.price {
 display:inline-block;
 font-weight:700;
 float:right;
 color:#22ddc0;
}

.itembox > ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.itembox > ul > li {
 line-height:3;
}

.radial {
 position:absolute;
 float:right;
 height:35px;
 width:35px;
 padding:2px;
 border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:50%;
 top:43%;
 right:10px;
}

.itembox .center-dot {
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 height:21px;
 width:21px;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
 border-radius:50%;
}

.itembox.user-selected .center-dot{
  display: block;
}

/* === (Int/Phn/TV) Thumbnails === */

/* UL Padding Adjustment for itembox */
.itembox > ul {
 padding-left:0;
}

.itembox > ul > li {
 margin:10px 0;
 padding-left:35px;
 line-height: 2;
}


/* === Price Bar === */


.price-bar:before {
 content:'';
 display:block;
 background:#e8e8e8;
 height:1px;
 margin:10px;
}

.price-bar p {
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 top:5px;
 left:10px;
 float:left;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:18px;
 color:#787878;
}

/* === Continue Button === */

.continue {
 display:inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
 border:0;
 border-radius:0;
 float:right;
 margin-right:10px;
}

.continue:hover {
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
}

/* === Phone Aux Specific === */

.phn-subtext {
 font-size:18px;
 color:#787878;
}

.unl-selection-container {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 position:relative;
}

.minibox {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 color:#787878;
 cursor:pointer;
 flex-grow:1;
 width:calc((100% * (1/4)) - 25px);
 margin:5px 0 0 25px;
 padding:5px;
 border:3px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:10px;
}

.minibox.mb-selected > p {
 color:#22ddc0;
}

.minibox:nth-child(4n+1) {
 margin:5px 0 0 0;
}

.minibox > h4 {
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:700;
}

/* Selection and Disabled Classes */

.mb-selected {
 border:3px solid #E16E5B;
}

.mb-disabled {
 background-color:#e8e8e8;
 color:#fff;
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="prime-aux"> <!-- Phone -->
        <h2>Phone</h2>
        <p class="aux-phn-subtext">Mix and match (up to 4 lines total)</p>
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <div id="race-phone" class="itembox-container">
          <div class="itembox boxes-2" data-price="20"> <!-- Unlimited -->
            <h4>Unlimited Phone <span class="price">$20/mo</span></h4>
            <h5 class="phn-subtext">+ $20/mo per additional line</h5>
            <ul>
              <li class="unl-icon icon-thumb">Unlimited nationwide calling</li>
              <li class="intl-icon icon-thumb">Low International Rates</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="unl-selection-container noselect"> <!-- Minibox Containers UNL -->
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <p>+ $20/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>2</h4>
                <p>+ $40/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>3</h4>
                <p>+ $60/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>4</h4>
                <p>+ $80/mo</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="itembox boxes-2" data-price="10"> <!-- Basic -->
            <h4>Basic Phone <span class="price">$10/mo</span></h4>
            <h5 class="phn-subtext">+ $10/mo per additional line</h5>
            <ul>
              <li class="unl-icon icon-thumb">Unlimited incoming calls</li>
              <li class="nation-icon icon-thumb">$0.05 cents/min outgoing, domestic calls</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="basic-selection-container noselect"> <!-- Minibox Containers Basic -->
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <p>+ $10/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>2</h4>
                <p>+ $15/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>3</h4>
                <p>+ $20/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>4</h4>
                <p>+ $25/mo</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price-bar">
          <p>Total: <span class="phn-price">$0/mo</span></p>
          <div id="phn-continue" class="continue btn">Continue without Phone</div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the user can select up to 4 boxes from either basic or unlimited, right? So it can be 4 from one, 0 from the other; 3 from one, 1 from the other; etc.?

Comment: Correct. If they've selected 4 unlimited lines then all of the basic lines should be disabled (and vice versa). So, as you say, they can select 3 from one and 1 from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some logic. Hope this is what you want

```js
var $unlminibox = $('.unl-selection-container > .minibox');
var $basicminibox = $('.basic-selection-container > .minibox');

$(function() {
  $unlminibox.on('click', toggleBox);
  $basicminibox.on('click', toggleBox);
})

function toggleBox(e) {
  if($(this).hasClass('mb-disabled')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass('mb-selected').siblings().removeClass('mb-selected');
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('mb-selected')) {
    racePhone = true;
  } else {
    racePhone = false;
  }
  var toDisable = $unlminibox.index($(this)) == -1 ? $unlminibox : $basicminibox;
    var curr = $unlminibox.index($(this)) != -1 ? $unlminibox : $basicminibox;

    var val = parseInt($('h4', $(this)).text());
    if(!$(this).hasClass('mb-disabled')) {
        var dec = false;
        for(var j = 0; j<curr.length; j++) {
            if($(curr[j]).hasClass('mb-selected')){
                dec=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!dec){
            for(var k = 0; k<toDisable.length; k++) {
                $(toDisable[k]).removeClass('mb-disabled');
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < toDisable.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('mb-selected') && (val + parseInt($(toDisable[i]).text()) > 4)) {
                $(toDisable[i]).addClass('mb-disabled')
            } else {
                $(toDisable[i]).removeClass('mb-disabled')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
h2 {
 color:#787878;
 font-weight:700;
}

.divider {
 background-color:#e8e8e8;
 height:2px;
}

.prime-aux {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 padding:15px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}

.aux-phn-subtext {
 color:#787878;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:600;
 font-style:italic;
}

.itembox-container {
 display:flex;
}

.boxes-2 {
 width:calc((100% - 25px)/2);
 margin:10px;
 padding: 10px;
}

.itembox {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:10px;
}

.user-selected {
 border:5px solid #E16E5B;
}

.itembox > h4 {
 color:#22ddc0;
 font-weight:700;
}

span.price {
 display:inline-block;
 font-weight:700;
 float:right;
 color:#22ddc0;
}

.itembox > ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.itembox > ul > li {
 line-height:3;
}

.radial {
 position:absolute;
 float:right;
 height:35px;
 width:35px;
 padding:2px;
 border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:50%;
 top:43%;
 right:10px;
}

.itembox .center-dot {
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 height:21px;
 width:21px;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
 border-radius:50%;
}

.itembox.user-selected .center-dot{
  display: block;
}

/* === (Int/Phn/TV) Thumbnails === */

/* UL Padding Adjustment for itembox */
.itembox > ul {
 padding-left:0;
}

.itembox > ul > li {
 margin:10px 0;
 padding-left:35px;
 line-height: 2;
}


/* === Price Bar === */


.price-bar:before {
 content:'';
 display:block;
 background:#e8e8e8;
 height:1px;
 margin:10px;
}

.price-bar p {
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 top:5px;
 left:10px;
 float:left;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:18px;
 color:#787878;
}

/* === Continue Button === */

.continue {
 display:inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
 border:0;
 border-radius:0;
 float:right;
 margin-right:10px;
}

.continue:hover {
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
}

/* === Phone Aux Specific === */

.phn-subtext {
 font-size:18px;
 color:#787878;
}

.unl-selection-container {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 position:relative;
}

.minibox {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 color:#787878;
 cursor:pointer;
 flex-grow:1;
 width:calc((100% * (1/4)) - 25px);
 margin:5px 0 0 25px;
 padding:5px;
 border:3px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:10px;
}

.minibox.mb-selected > p {
 color:#22ddc0;
}

.minibox:nth-child(4n+1) {
 margin:5px 0 0 0;
}

.minibox > h4 {
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:700;
}

/* Selection and Disabled Classes */

.mb-selected {
 border:3px solid #E16E5B;
}

.mb-disabled {
 background-color:#e8e8e8;
 color:#fff;
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="prime-aux"> <!-- Phone -->
        <h2>Phone</h2>
        <p class="aux-phn-subtext">Mix and match (up to 4 lines total)</p>
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <div id="race-phone" class="itembox-container">
          <div class="itembox boxes-2" data-price="20"> <!-- Unlimited -->
            <h4>Unlimited Phone <span class="price">$20/mo</span></h4>
            <h5 class="phn-subtext">+ $20/mo per additional line</h5>
            <ul>
              <li class="unl-icon icon-thumb">Unlimited nationwide calling</li>
              <li class="intl-icon icon-thumb">Low International Rates</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="unl-selection-container noselect"> <!-- Minibox Containers UNL -->
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <p>+ $20/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>2</h4>
                <p>+ $40/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>3</h4>
                <p>+ $60/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>4</h4>
                <p>+ $80/mo</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="itembox boxes-2" data-price="10"> <!-- Basic -->
            <h4>Basic Phone <span class="price">$10/mo</span></h4>
            <h5 class="phn-subtext">+ $10/mo per additional line</h5>
            <ul>
              <li class="unl-icon icon-thumb">Unlimited incoming calls</li>
              <li class="nation-icon icon-thumb">$0.05 cents/min outgoing, domestic calls</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="basic-selection-container noselect"> <!-- Minibox Containers Basic -->
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <p>+ $10/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>2</h4>
                <p>+ $15/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>3</h4>
                <p>+ $20/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox">
                <h4>4</h4>
                <p>+ $25/mo</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price-bar">
          <p>Total: <span class="phn-price">$0/mo</span></p>
          <div id="phn-continue" class="continue btn">Continue without Phone</div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's very close. Is a toggle possible? Currently, clicking on 4 lines (from either box) will add the class, but deselecting the option won't remove the `mb-disabled` class.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to have helped. If you're satisfied, can you mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

## Heading

Try This Code.I have added a **data-val** attribute in html have a look over it

```js
var $unlminibox = $('.unl-selection-container > .minibox');
var $basicminibox = $('.basic-selection-container > .minibox');

$(function() {
  $unlminibox.on('click', toggleBox);
  $basicminibox.on('click', toggleBox);
})

function toggleBox(e) {

  var getClicked = e.currentTarget;

  if($(getClicked).hasClass('mb-selected')){
   $('#race-phone div').removeClass('mb-selected');
   $('#race-phone div').removeClass('mb-disabled');
   return false;
  }


  var getValue = $(getClicked).attr('data-val');
  var getParent = $(getClicked).parent('div');

  var calculateValue = 4 - getValue;

  $('#race-phone div').removeClass('mb-selected');
  $basicminibox.removeClass('mb-disabled');
  $unlminibox.removeClass('mb-disabled'); 

  $(getClicked).addClass('mb-selected');
  if($(getParent).hasClass('unl-selection-container')){

    

    var disableElement = $basicminibox.filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr("data-val") > calculateValue;
    })

    $(disableElement).addClass('mb-disabled'); 

  }else{

    
    var disableElement = $unlminibox.filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr("data-val") > calculateValue;
    })
    
    $(disableElement).addClass('mb-disabled'); 

  }
}
```

```css
h2 {
  color:#787878;
  font-weight:700;
}

.divider {
  background-color:#e8e8e8;
  height:2px;
}

.prime-aux {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:15px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}

.aux-phn-subtext {
  color:#787878;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:600;
  font-style:italic;
}

.itembox-container {
  display:flex;
}

.boxes-2 {
  width:calc((100% - 25px)/2);
  margin:10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.itembox {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.user-selected {
  border:5px solid #E16E5B;
}

.itembox > h4 {
  color:#22ddc0;
  font-weight:700;
}

span.price {
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:700;
  float:right;
  color:#22ddc0;
}

.itembox > ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.itembox > ul > li {
  line-height:3;
}

.radial {
  position:absolute;
  float:right;
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
  padding:2px;
  border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:43%;
  right:10px;
}

.itembox .center-dot {
  display:none;
  position:relative;
  height:21px;
  width:21px;
  background-color:#E16E5B;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.itembox.user-selected .center-dot{
  display: block;
}

/* === (Int/Phn/TV) Thumbnails === */

/* UL Padding Adjustment for itembox */
.itembox > ul {
  padding-left:0;
}

.itembox > ul > li {
  margin:10px 0;
  padding-left:35px;
  line-height: 2;
}


/* === Price Bar === */


.price-bar:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  background:#e8e8e8;
  height:1px;
  margin:10px;
}

.price-bar p {
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  top:5px;
  left:10px;
  float:left;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:18px;
  color:#787878;
}

/* === Continue Button === */

.continue {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#E16E5B;
  border:0;
  border-radius:0;
  float:right;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.continue:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#E16E5B;
}

/* === Phone Aux Specific === */

.phn-subtext {
  font-size:18px;
  color:#787878;
}

.unl-selection-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  position:relative;
}

.minibox {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  color:#787878;
  cursor:pointer;
  flex-grow:1;
  width:calc((100% * (1/4)) - 25px);
  margin:5px 0 0 25px;
  padding:5px;
  border:3px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.minibox.mb-selected > p {
  color:#22ddc0;
}

.minibox:nth-child(4n+1) {
  margin:5px 0 0 0;
}

.minibox > h4 {
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:700;
}

/* Selection and Disabled Classes */

.mb-selected {
  border:3px solid #E16E5B;
}

.mb-disabled {
  background-color:#e8e8e8;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="prime-aux"> <!-- Phone -->
        <h2>Phone</h2>
        <p class="aux-phn-subtext">Mix and match (up to 4 lines total)</p>
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <div id="race-phone" class="itembox-container">
          <div class="itembox boxes-2" data-price="20"> <!-- Unlimited -->
            <h4>Unlimited Phone <span class="price">$20/mo</span></h4>
            <h5 class="phn-subtext">+ $20/mo per additional line</h5>
            <ul>
              <li class="unl-icon icon-thumb">Unlimited nationwide calling</li>
              <li class="intl-icon icon-thumb">Low International Rates</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="unl-selection-container noselect"> <!-- Minibox Containers UNL -->
              <div class="minibox" data-val="1">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <p>+ $20/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox" data-val="2">
                <h4>2</h4>
                <p>+ $40/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox" data-val="3">
                <h4>3</h4>
                <p>+ $60/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox" data-val="4">
                <h4>4</h4>
                <p>+ $80/mo</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="itembox boxes-2" data-price="10"> <!-- Basic -->
            <h4>Basic Phone <span class="price">$10/mo</span></h4>
            <h5 class="phn-subtext">+ $10/mo per additional line</h5>
            <ul>
              <li class="unl-icon icon-thumb">Unlimited incoming calls</li>
              <li class="nation-icon icon-thumb">$0.05 cents/min outgoing, domestic calls</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="basic-selection-container noselect"> <!-- Minibox Containers Basic -->
              <div class="minibox" data-val="1">
                <h4>1</h4>
                <p>+ $10/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox" data-val="2">
                <h4>2</h4>
                <p>+ $15/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox" data-val="3">
                <h4>3</h4>
                <p>+ $20/mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="minibox" data-val="4">
                <h4>4</h4>
                <p>+ $25/mo</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price-bar">
          <p>Total: <span class="phn-price">$0/mo</span></p>
          <div id="phn-continue" class="continue btn">Continue without Phone</div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it breaks the original toggle functionality. After making a selection I am unable to deselect the option.